# Choose list according to list name which is variable in python

Tags: python, list

For example I've created a set of list:

```
LIST_chr1=[]
LIST_chr2=[]
LIST_chr3=[]
...
...
```

Now when processing the text, for certain line, if I get "chr2", then I need to use LIST_chr2 thus select this list, how should I point to this specific list according to the list name?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, you don't want to do something like this ...

You could try:

```
vname = 'chr3'
list_I_want = globals()['LIST_'+vname]
```

Although, usually the **MUCH BETTER** way to do something like this is to store the lists in a `dict` in the first place

```
my_list_dict = dict(LIST_chr1=[],LIST_chr2=[],LIST_chr3=[],...)
```

and then:

```
list_I_want = my_list_dict['LIST_'+vname]
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a better job for a list of lists or a dictionary. For example, you could just use a structure like this:

```
>>> lists = [["list 1","contents"],[],[]]
>>> lists[0]
['list 1', 'contents']
```

(where the elements 'list 1' and 'contents' are the legitimate elements of LIST_chr1).

To be clear, if you need to access the lists by some identifier, use a dictionary as in the other example, but if you are just getting the list based on a specific number, this is the way to go.